# The onclick event doesn't work on reloading elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I have created a user support system to enable users to contact the moderators of my website in case they need help with their account and the opposite.

As of recently, ***new messages sent to or by the users get loaded only if the page is refreshed***, which is not very convenient as a user may sign out without refreshing and therefore not get the message soon.

To counter that, I thought of implementing a `setInterval()` sending an AJAX request ***every 1 minute*** and reloading the messages from the database, so that if new ones exist they will be shown.

While it actually works and reloads the messages, when I click on a message to open it and read it ***the `onclick` event is not fired***. This happens for all messages without exception.

I thought that the problem was that `setInterval()` ***reloaded all the messages every minute instead of checking if new messages exist and reload them only in that case***, but despite performing this check in my PHP file the problem still persists.

---

### My PHP code for a notification:

```
<?php
  $message_status = ($status[$a] === "Read") ? "-open" : ""; ?>
?>

<div class="dashboard-notifs-content">
  <p>
    <i class="fa fa-folder<?php echo $message_status; ?> fa-fw">&nbsp;</i>
    <a class = "user-notifs" notif-id = "<?php echo $ID[$a]; ?>"
       subject = "<?php echo $subject[$a]; ?>" message = "<?php echo $message[$a]; ?>"
       status = "<?php echo $status[$a]; ?>"><?php echo $subject[$a]; ?></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

### My code for the `onclick` event:

```
// Show message in preview
$(".user-notifs").on("click", function() {
    // Declare variables and assign to them the content of their respective attributes
    var current = this;
    var id = this.getAttribute("notif-id");
    var subject = this.getAttribute("subject");
    var message = this.getAttribute("message");
    var status = this.getAttribute("status");

    // Assign notification-id to the preview window
    document.getElementById("user-notif-preview").setAttribute("notif-id", id);

    // Display the preview lightbox and show the message
    lightbox.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("user-subject").value = subject;
    document.getElementById("user-message").value = message;

    /* Check if the notification has already been opened
    to mark it as read in the database */
    if (status === "Unread") {
        // Mark notification as opened
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState === 1) {
                current.previousElementSibling.className = "fa fa-folder-open fa-fw";
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "notifs.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("notif_status=Read&notif_id=" + id);
    }
});
```

### My code for `setInterval()`:

```
var notifications = document.getElementById("dashboard-notifs");

// Update the notifications
setInterval(function() {
   var yhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var number = $("#dashboard-notifs").children(".dashboard-notifs-content").length;
   yhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (yhttp.readyState === 4 && yhttp.status === 200) {
         // Display the notifications if the response is not empty
         if (yhttp.responseText.length !== 0) {
            notifications.innerHTML = yhttp.responseText;
         }
      }
   };
   yhttp.open("POST", "update.php", true);
   yhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   yhttp.send("content=notifs&number=" + number);
}, 5000);
```

---

I have only managed to find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706340/jquery-click-not-working-with-setinterval) on Stack Overflow, which is kind of similar, but unfortunately ***none of the answers there solves my issue***.

Comment: you'll have to reassign the onclick eventhandler to the newly added elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are directly binding the `onclick` event using `on`. You should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

You can write the `onclick` event in this way.

```
$(document).on("click", ".user-notifs",function() {
   //script goes here
});
```

Instead of `document` you can also use the parent element closer to the target element.

```
$(class_or_id_of_closer_parent_ele).on("click", ".user-notifs", function() {
    //script goes here
});
```

Comment: It works! I have to attach the handler to its grand grand parent for it to work, which is the element nesting the PHP code I have in my question. I also read the documentation you provided and it helped me get a better grasp of why it wasn't working. You've been a bigger help that you think and you deserve an upvote and a check mark! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AngelPolitis glad to help u. :)